# meteor camera package gives warning

Tags: meteor

I am using meteor camera package(https://github.com/meteor/mobile-packages/blob/master/packages/mdg:camera/README.md).
But it gives warning and do not perform capture onclick event. Could anybody help?

Here is my code:

Contact item template:

```
<template name="contactItem">
  <div class="card-panel contacts #ffe57f amber accent-1">
    <div class="row item">
      <div class="col l4 image-div" id="{{number}}">
        <img src="{{photo}}" class="circle responsive-img capture">
      </div>      
      <div class="col l6">
        <div class="row item">  
          <div class="col l12">
            <a href="{{pathFor 'contactPage'}}">{{title}}</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row item">  
          <div class="col l6">  
            {{#if notOwnContact}}submitted by {{author}}{{/if}} 
          </div>
          <div class="col l2">
            {{#if ownContact}}<a href="{{pathFor 'contactEdit'}}" class="waves-effect waves-purple btn">Edit</a>{{/if}}
          </div>
          <div class="col l2 offset-l2">
            {{#if ownContact}}<a href="#" class="waves-effect waves-purple btn status">{{status}}</a>{{/if}}  
          </div>            
        </div>  
      </div>
      <div class="col l2 number-div">
        {{number}}
      </div>    
    </div>  
  </div>      
</template> 

Template.contactItem.events({
  'click .capture': function(e) {
    MeteorCamera.getPicture({}, function(error,data) {
      var target = $(e.target);
      var parent = target.parent();
      var uncle = parent.siblings(".number-div"); 
      var num = $(parent).attr('id')
      //$(target).attr("scr",data);
      var currentContact = Contacts.findOne({number: num});
      currentContact.statusImage = data;
      //currentContact.status = "public";
      console.log(currentContact);
      console.log(data);  
    });  
  }
});
```

Comment: I forgot : Name of the collection is Contacts. And capture onclick event is constructed on the img  which is inside of the div with id="{{number}}"

Comment: Errors : Warning: Blaze.render without a parent element is deprecated. You must specify where to insert the rendered content.

Comment: Warning: Blaze.insert has been deprecated.  Specify where to insert the rendered content in the call to Blaze.render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly as the warnings say: Blaze.render without a parent element and Blaze.Insert have been deprecated. This means that the package is for older versions of Meteor.

See the docs here for the latest Blaze documentation:
http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/blaze_render

That camera package you linked to hasn't been updated in a long time. If you want, you can make changes to the package by adding it as a local package and fixing up the lines of code that are causing a warning. This might also fix your problem of the photo not capturing, although that might be another issue.

I'd post an issue in the GitHub repo notifying mdg to update the package to the latest version of meteor.